# Qt3D Project does not show any result after succesful compiling

Tags: c++, qt

When I compile my Qt3D Project everything is OK, but after it starts nothing happends(no new window is open). In Qt console is said that program was succesfully started and I even can find process with my app in Windows Task Manager, but after approximately 30 sec Qt says that app suddenly was closed(during this time no new windows were opened). My main.cpp code:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <Qt3DCore>
#include <Qt3DExtras>
#include <Qt3DRender>

Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow window;

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = createScene();

    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = window.camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(60.0f, float(window.width()) / window.height(), 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    window.setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}

Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene()
{
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *resultEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;

    Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh *torusMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QTorusMesh(resultEntity);
    torusMesh->setRadius(15.0f);
    torusMesh->setMinorRadius(6.0f);
    torusMesh->setSlices(16);
    torusMesh->setRings(32);

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *torusMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(resultEntity);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *torusTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(resultEntity);

    resultEntity->addComponent(torusMesh);
    resultEntity->addComponent(torusMaterial);
    resultEntity->addComponent(torusTransform);

    return resultEntity;
}
```

Comment: Weird, on Linux your code works for me in Qt 5.9, Qt 5.10 and Qt 5.11. Did you try to clean the project, run qmake and build afterwards? Sometimes this fixes issues.

Comment: If rebuilding does not work see the debug output either in Qt Creator or start the app from console and see what it says. Sometimes it may relate to OpenGL and the way Qt compiled.